# Multivariable calculus problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can you please explain how to differentiate $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x-y$ ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of a directional derivative?

Comment: No, I do not. I started looking at it, how can I use it to address this question?

Answer (score 1):

For a general co-ordinate $u$, $$\frac{df}{du} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$

So for $u = x-y$, we have:

$$\frac{df}{du} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

Note that the derivative given above is different to the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ which will in general depend on a given parameterisation of the curve as $f = f(u,v)$, as mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Thank you, can you please say what  determines the parameterization of the curve?  I am new to this subject. The function is of the form f(x,y) = (a-b x)^2 - (c - d y)^2 and the question is how does f change when (x-y) change?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the other variable in your coordinate system is. For example, if your new system is $u = x - y$, $v = x$ and $f(x, y) = x + y$, then 
$$
f(u, v) = -u + 2v
$$ 
and so the derivative with respect to $u$ is $-1$. But if the new system is $u = x - y$, $v = y$, then
$$
f(u, v) = u + 2v
$$
and the derivative is $1$.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure what do you mean by the other variable. What determines how to define the new system? The function is of the form f(x,y) = (a-b x)^2 - (c - d y)^2 and the question is how does f change when (x-y) change?